# Counting the triangles that can be formed from segments of given lengths

Tags: c++, algorithm, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, computational-geometry

### Problem Statement:

> Given an unsorted array of positive integers. Find the number of
>   triangles that can be formed with three different array elements as
>   lengths of three sides of triangles.
>
> **Input:**  The first line of the input contains T denoting the number of testcases. First line of test case is the length of array N and
>   second line of test case are its elements.
>
> **Output:** Number of possible triangles are displayed to the user.
>
> **Constraints:**
>
> \$1 \le T \le 200\$
>   \$3 \le N \le 10^7\$
>   \$1 \le \mathrm{arr}[i] \le 10^3\$
>
> **Example:**
>
> **Input:**
>
> ```
> 2
> 3
> 3 5 4
> 5
> 6 4 9 7 8
> ```
>
> **Output:**
>
> ```
> 1
> 10
> ```

### Algorithm:

The efficient \$O(n^2)\$ algorithm for solving this problem has been explained [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-number-of-triangles-possible/).

> Let \$a\$, \$b\$ and \$c\$ be three sides. The below condition must
>   hold for a triangle (Sum of two sides is greater than the third side)
>   i) \$a + b > c\$ ii) \$b + c > a\$ iii) \$a + c > b\$
>
> Following are steps to count triangle.
>
> 1. Sort the array in non-decreasing order.
> 2. Initialize two pointers `i` and `j` to first and second elements respectively, and initialize count of triangles as `0`.
> 3. Fix `i` and `j` and find the rightmost index `k` (or largest `arr[k]`) such that `arr[i] + arr[j] > arr[k]`. The number of
>      triangles that can be formed with `arr[i]` and `arr[j]` as two sides
>      is `k – j`. Add `k – j` to count of triangles.
>
>    Let us consider `arr[i]` as \$a\$, `arr[j]` as \$b\$ and all
>      elements between `arr[j+1]` and `arr[k]` as \$c\$. The above mentioned
>      conditions (ii) and (iii) are satisfied because `arr[i] < arr[j] <
>      arr[k]`. And we check for condition (i) when we pick `k`.
> 4. Increment `j` to fix the second element again.
>
>    Note that in step 3, we can use the previous value of `k`. The reason is simple, if we know that the value of `arr[i] + arr[j-1]` is
>      greater than `arr[k]`, then we can say `arr[i] + arr[j]` will also be
>      greater than `arr[k]`, because the array is sorted in increasing
>      order.
> 5. If `j` has reached end, then increment `i`. Initialize `j` as `i + 1`, `k` as `i+2` and repeat the steps 3 and 4.

### Code Implementation (in C++):

This is my implementation of the algorithm in C++ (using vectors instead of raw arrays):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;
int triangles (vector<int> &V, int N);

int main () {
    int T;
    cin >> T;
    vector<int> V;
    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
    {
        int N;
        cin >> N;
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
           int temp;
           cin >> temp;
           V.push_back(temp);
        }
        cout << triangles (V, N) << endl;
        V.clear();
    }
    return 0;
}

int triangles (vector<int> &V, int N)
{
    int sum = 0;
    sort(V.begin(), V.end());
    for (int i = 0; i <= N-3; i++)
    {   
        int k = i + 2;
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= N-2; j++)
        {
            while (k < N && V[k] < V[i] + V[j])
                k++;
            sum += k-j-1;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

### Problem:

The code gives the perfectly correct output for any input, however, when I submit the code on [GeekForGeeks Practice](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/count-possible-triangles/0), it says

> Your program took more time than expected (Time Limit Exceeded).
>   Expected Time Limit < 2.656sec. Hint: Please optimize your code and submit again.

At this point, I'm not sure how to optimize my code. Any ideas? Do I necessarily need to use an array instead of a vector in order to speed up the program?

Comment: Choose telling names for your variables. From a 9 second glance at the source code, I could not recognise the algorithm described following `The efficient O(n²) … explained here.`: document what problem is solved with what algorithm *in your program source*.

Comment: There's a comment on the linked page that says: "I am very surprised that qsort() is not giving a TLE, whereas std::sort() does." Perhaps that's one place to start looking for an answer?

Comment: @user1118321 That almost guarantees that the commentator is misusing `std::sort`.

Comment: Fair point. Are there any large input files available to test the code with? If so, it can be profiled. If not, it's kind of a pain to come up with some to do the testing.

Comment: If \$N\$ might be \$10^7\$ then you don't want to use a \$\Theta(N^2)\$ algorithm.

Comment: @Peter Do you happen to know a better algorithm for such cases?

Comment: See AJNeufeld's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Don't use `using namespace std;`.  It is extremely bad practice and will ruin your life.**  You will have trouble on common identifiers like `count`, `size`, etc.  See [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721) for more information.

The input format is extremely awkward, but this seems to be beyond your control, so I'll leave it alone.

Instead of using a linear search as you are doing in your loop, it might be beneficial to do a binary search if the amount of data is large.  (This needs some testing.)  Also, use standard algorithms to make your code more readable.

Also, in this very case, a dynamic vector may not be the best way to appeal to the timer.  (I'm not sure how I would phrase that.)  `reserve` may help.  You can try using a static vector like [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/226757) because you know that the size is below a limit.

Answer (score 6):

The statement `V.push_back(temp);` can be inefficient, as the vector `V` may need to be reallocated multiple times.

Use [`std::vector::reserve(N)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) to ensure sufficient space exists in the vector before reading in the data to avoid multiple reallocations.

---

> \$3 \le N \le 10^7\$
>   \$1 \le \mathrm{arr}[i] \le 10^3\$

With \$10^7\$ pigeons and \$10^3\$ holes, many holes can have over 10,000 pigeons!  You might want to consider an array of counts indexed by side length.  No sort required; it is automatically sorted.  But your algorithm will need considerable reworking.

Answer (score 3):

Even after using [`reserve`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/), as suggested by [@L.F.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/188857/l-f) and [@AJNeufeld](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/100620/ajneufeld), there was no considerable speedup and it was still timing out. So I decided to use dynamically allocated **arrays** instead. I also removed `using namespace std`, and instead only imported those `std` functions which are required in the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::sort;

long long int triangles (int arr[], int N);

int main () {
    int T;
    cin >> T;
    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
    {
        int N;
        cin >> N;
        int *arr = new int[N];
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
        cin >> arr[j];
        }
        cout << triangles (arr, N) << endl;
        delete arr;
    }
    return 0;
}

long long int triangles (int arr[], int N)
{
    long long int sum = 0;
    sort(arr, arr+N);
    for (int i = 0; i <= N-3; i++)
    {   
        int k = i + 2;
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= N-2; j++)
        {
            while (k < N && arr[k] < (arr[i] + arr[j]))
                k++;
            sum += k-j-1;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Note that the data type of the `sum` which is returned by the `triangles()` function must be *at least* `long long int`, as it otherwise [exceeds the range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) of regular `int`.

Comment: That geeksforgeeks page is very wrong.  Prior to C++20, the range of `int` is an implementation-defined superset of integers in [-32767, 32767], and the range of `long int` is an implementation-defined superset of integers in [-2,147,483,647, 2,147,483,647].  You should use `long long int`.  I recommended that you use a more accurate C++ reference like https://en.cppreference.com.

Comment: @L.F. Thanks, I will check that reference. By the way, do you happen to have any idea about why dynamically allocated arrays outperform vectors in this context? According to the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664272/is-stdvector-so-much-slower-than-plain-arrays), they should approximately have the same speed/performance.

Comment: Vectors are more flexible and do a lot of bookkeeping for you.  It is much more than just a dynamically allocated array.  So with extremist timing, it can be "observably" slower than arrays.  In practice, this small difference probably doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Note that `std:;cin`, `std::cout` and `std::endl` are used only inside `main()`, so the scope of those `using` statements can be reduced.  Similarly, `std::sort` is used only in `triangles()` - and there, only once, so is the `using` really necessary?

Comment: @L.F., surely the type to use (ever since C++11 came out) is one of the types defined in `cstdint`? (Well, or it would be if any of them were wide enough. The output requires 117 bits in the worst case, and 128-bit integer types are non-standard extensions).

Comment: @PeterTaylor I have a bit of trouble understanding your comment.  Do you mean that I shouldn't have suggested `long long int`?

Comment: @L.F., yes. I would have suggested `uint_64t`, but then I realised that it's not wide enough.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I get your point.  Well, `mpz_class` then :)  I think that's beyond the scope of the challenge.